# Jquerymobile demo not working on Blackberry curve 8520

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, blackberry

I am trying to see [demo](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/) of jquerymobile in blackberry curve 8520, but not displaying properly.

Is it because of old version of my mobile or something else?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I belive the 8520 runs BBOS5? Which will cause all realms of trouble.

Comment: Is this bcoz of my mobile old browser ?

Comment: Yes. Do you have the app store on yoru blackberry? Have a look for other browsers in the app store. This may help you :)

Comment: but am developing Jquerymobile application which will be used by many users in future, but how can i depend on other browser. I need to work it on default browser of BB

Comment: Unfortunatly that is one of RIM's major downfalls. Its mobile internet browsers. Sorry!